# How to customize Google Chart

Tags: google-app-engine, google-visualization

I'm creating new chart table with Google Chart. I want to get the result rank wise. For Example:

A:10
B:5
C:2
D:1

So the result should display something like this

D,C,B,A

Is there any way way to do that. (I've added minus to values. But its not proper way right?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

Using the base code [here](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#data_table_advanced_population) as a base:

```
var drawVisualizations = function() {
  // Create and populate a data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Force');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Level');

  // Add 2 rows.
  // google.visualization.DataTable.addRows() can take a 2-dim array of values.
  data.addRows([['Fire', 1], ['Water', 5]]);

  // Add one more row.
  data.addRow(['sand', 4]);

  // Draw a table with this data table.
  var originalVisualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('original_data_table'));
  originalVisualization.draw(data);

  // Clone the data table and modify it a little.
  var modifiedData = data.clone();

  // Modify existing cell.
  modifiedData.setCell(1, 1, 666);

  // Sort the data by the 2nd column (counting from 0).
  modifiedData.sort(1);

  // Insert rows in the middle of the data table.
  modifiedData.insertRows(2, [['new fire', 14], ['new water', 41]]);

  // Draw a table with this data table.
  var modifiedVisualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('modified_data_table'));
  modifiedVisualization.draw(modifiedData);
}
```

As you can see, using "sort()" on your datatable will sort. Documentation on the sort command is located [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_sort)

Comment: Thanks. I tried, and its not working on BarChart. Pls visit the following url https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart

Comment: That is just the default bar chart. Did you perform a sort on the datatable there? If so, what was your code? Simply saying it doesn't work (when it clearly does in the example posted) doesn't really help.

Comment: I'm sorry, It was a mistake. I've modified the code. http://pastebin.com/e7gDCnRR. Please copy the code and paste in google web chart page.